# Loop for extracting hazard ratios and confidence intervals for factor variables

Tags: r

I have a data set with 100,000 cases and 81 factor variables with 4 levels each and I run a loop for multiple regression for each variable adjusted for age and sex in r. My data set looks like this:

```
inst time status age sex ph.ecog ph.karno pat.karno meal.cal wt.loss
1    3  306      2  74   1       1       1       1     4      1
2    3  455      2  68   1       0       2       3     4      2
3    3 1010      1  56   1       0       3       4     NA     3
```

```
covariates <- c(var1, var2, ... var81)
purrr:: map(covariates, ~coxph(as.formula(paste("Surv(Time,Event) ~ Age + Sex +", .x)), data=mydata))
```

The output should include the hazard ratios and confidence intervals for age, sex and for each level of the factor variable, like this:

```
HZ     (95%CI) 
Age 0.0000 0.0-0.00 
Sex 
Var1(1) 
Var1(2) 
Var1(3) 
Var1(4)
```

I was wondering if there is a way for me to export in excel
only the hazard ratios and confidence intervals only for the 4 levels of the factor variables.

Comment: Possible, but difficult without a reproducible sample. Can you run dput(head(mydata)) and dput(covariates) and share the structure here?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I cannot share my covariates because of confidentiality issues but I shared a similar example. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
out <- purrr:: map(covariates, ~coxph(as.formula(paste("Surv(Time,Event) ~ Age + Sex +", .x)), data=mydata))

sm <- lapply(out, function(x) as.data.frame(summary(x)[["conf.int"]][,c("lower .95", "upper .95")]))

for (i in names(sm)) {
  write.csv(sm[[i]], paste0(i, ".csv"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think it doesn't work. In the end the results are not written in the csv file. Do you have any suggestions why it didn' t work?

Comment: Are you getting sm as a list object with each element being a data frame of confidence intervals?

Comment: Yes this is what I am getting

Comment: It should work, then. Ensure that you're checking at the working directory.

Comment: You could add some dummy variables in covariates, so that we could run the codes and suggest.